# Scope issue, not returning?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, it should log the data from the link, but it is logging undefined. I believe the problem may be with the scope, here is my code, thanks.

```
function getData(link) {
    var string;
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        string = String(data);
    })
    return string;
}
console.log(getData("http://www.industus.com"));
```

Comment: You are running into an issue of asynchronous callback - where `return string` is executed before `$.get` returns

Comment: This is not a scope issue but an asynchronous issue. Here is the canonical answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

You are making an asynchronous request but treating the result asynchronously. Make a synchronous request if you want that, or put the `console.log` statement inside the success callback function.

Comment: How can I make synchronous? I don't want it to log every time you call the function, only if you use `console.log(getData(link));`

Comment: You can't, you are misunderstanding how asynchronous code works. Considering that console.log() is a debugging statement used during development, you can probably replace the desire to log the result to the console by simply looking at the networking tab in the development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as a synchronous call.

```
function getData(link) {
  var string;
  $.ajax({
    type:"method_type",
    url: link,
    dataType: "data_type",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
      string = String(data);
    }
  });
}
```

If you want to keep it async,

```
$.get(link, function(data) {
    string = String(data);
    // console.log here 
});
```

Comment: Do not use `async: false`. It will do what you expect for your example, but if you leave this code in for production it is more likely to cause user experience problems. Frankly I don't understand why synchronous XHR requests are even allowed.

Comment: @Nate, yes, since default behavior is synchronous, `async:false` is unnecessary. And I don't like synchronous calls myself. I just told him both the approaches.